# Trouble with java GUI. I can't get JRadioButtons to display in JLabel

Tags: java, swing, layout, jlabel, jradiobutton

I am new to Java; but I'm having a blast. I feel like I'm missing something really simple; but I can't figure it out.

I want the RadioButtons to be displayed inside the JFrame."

```
public class HelloWorldFrame extends JFrame
{
    private TitledBorder title;

    public HelloWorldFrame()
    {
        super("Hello World!                  ");
        JFrame helloWorld = new JFrame();
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        title = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Language");
        title.setTitleJustification(TitledBorder.LEFT);
        label.setBorder(title);
        add(label);

        setSize(300, 200);

        JRadioButton button1 = new JRadioButton("English");
        JRadioButton button2 = new JRadioButton("French");
        JRadioButton button3 = new JRadioButton("Spanish");
        ButtonGroup bG = new ButtonGroup();
        bG.add(button1);
        bG.add(button2);
        bG.add(button3);
        label.add(button1);
        label.add(button2);
        label.add(button3);
        helloWorld.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
}


//The main class starts here

public class HelloWorldApp
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame helloWorld = new HelloWorldFrame();
        helloWorld.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not too sure you can add buttons to a JLabel, it's for displaying text. You may want to add them to a JPanel instead.

Comment: @Takendarkk It was so simple. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Takendarkk Could be the OP is trying to set the background image of the window....

Comment: So you CAN add buttons, etc.. to a label. Learn something new everyday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first question is why?  Why do you want to add the radio buttons to a `JLabel`?

Having said that, you can set the labels layout manager to something other then it's default value of `null`...

```
label.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
label.add(button1);
label.add(button2);
label.add(button3);
```

Next...your class extends from `JFrame`, but in your constructor, you are creating another `JFrame`, this means that when you do...

```
JFrame helloWorld = new HelloWorldFrame();
helloWorld.setVisible(true);
```

Nothing will be displayed, because nothing has been added to the frame.

Instead, make your class extend from something like `JFrame` and then add that to your `JFrame` in `main`

**Updated**

I just did some testing and doing this (adding buttons to a label) won't work well, as the `JLabel` calculates it's preferred size based on the text and icon, not it's contents (like something like `JPanel` would)...just saying...

Comment: Sane programmer asks a mad question. MadProgrammer provides a sane answer lol

Comment: @AlexYan Dogs and cats living together, the world is coming to an end :P